# Using iPhone with Ubuntu 14.04 and Davical

Tags: thunderbird, iphone, calendar

i switched from an old Debian 6 Server (using davical) to Ubuntu 14.04 (using Davical too).
The Caldav calender is accessed with Thunderbird/Lightning (works fine) and iPhone. The iPhone caused the trouble.

With Debian 6 i use this line to connect the iphone to the caldav calendar:
 http://192.168.1.1/davical/caldav.php/user/home/

For Ubuntu 14.04 i use this:
 http://192.168.1.1/davical/caldav.php/user/calendar/

From Thunderbird it works fine. But the iPhone only see the entrys created with it. But not the normal from Thunderbird.

Has anybody worked with caldav and iphone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Today I can present a solution for a particularly nice problem:

How to connect an iPhone to a Caldav calendar using Ubuntu 14.04. So far I had connected iPhones to a Debian 6 server which actually worked perfectly. However, the outdated Davical version had some disadvantages in combination with Outlook.

That’s why I decided to install Davical on the Ubuntu 14.04 Server as well to the effect that it also offers the calendar service.

The connection of Thunderbird/Lightning worked perfectly as well and also Outlook synchronizes the data with the server by means of the Evo commands. Only the iPhone has proved to be problematic.

So far I proceeded in such a way that I installed the calendars in Lightning then imported the data and finally entered the URL of the calendar in the iPhone.

Up to now the composition of the URL has been like this:

http://192.168.1.1/davical/caldav.php/user/calendar/
(for Debian’s older version of Davical 0.9 it must be home instead of calendar)

Along this path the iPhone does not find the calendar.

The solution is to first of all configure the calendar on the iPhone. Here you select the address again as above. When you have saved the calendar, you log in to the web interface of Davical and navigate to the user
(user functions -> user display) and select the user there. Under “collections of principal” you will find a link in the following format:

/davical/caldav.php/user/D553F027-30BE-1F30-BAB2-5F8AC31F74D2/

You have to insert this link in Thunderbird/Lightning as a URL to the calendar. In our example this would be:

http://192.168.100.1/davical/caldav.php/user/D553F027-30BE-1F30-BAB2-5F8AC31F74D2/